# System.InvalidCastException

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Working with MVC 2 ad with the help of some friends I *thought* all the errors were fixed, until I ran into this behemoth of an error (personally the largest exception explanation I've ever caused.

**Error Message**

> [A]GodsCreationTaxidermy.Data.EFUnitOfWork
>   cannot be cast to
>   [B]GodsCreationTaxidermy.Data.EFUnitOfWork.
>   Type A originates from
>   'GodsCreationTaxidermy.Core,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' in the context
>   'Default' at location
>   'C:\Users\Richard L.
>   McCutchen\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\3d450750\bcfb1c91\assembly\dl3\200754f0\6a7f303e_1418cc01\GodsCreationTaxidermy.Core.DLL'.
>   Type B originates from
>   'GodsCreationTaxidermy.Data,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' in the context
>   'Default' at location
>   'C:\Users\Richard L.
>   McCutchen\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\3d450750\bcfb1c91\assembly\dl3\5d86cf1a\5d1f256f_0118cc01\GodsCreationTaxidermy.Data.DLL'.

And it comes on this line (in GenericRepository):

```
public UoW GetCurrentUnitOfWork<UoW>() where UoW : IUnitOfWork
{
    return (UoW)UnitOfWork.Current; //<< error happens here
}
```

As was suggested I deleted all the ASP.NET files from the temp directory and it changed noting.

I'm pretty sure that this method is the only one calling that , which in turn triggers the error

```
private ObjectContext Context
{
    get
    {
        if (_context == null)
        {
            return _context = GetCurrentUnitOfWork<GodsCreationTaxidermy.Data.EFUnitOfWork>().Context;
        }
        return _context;
    }
}
```

So, has anyone ran into something similar they can help with?

Comment: Check that the reference is to the project and not the dll? Also, don't return inside the if in the Context property.

Comment: I'm sorry but I', not understanding the first part of your reply, I did remove the return inside the if and of course nothing changed

Comment: Anyone know how to get trough this error? It's starting to drive me nuts ;)

Comment: Have you recently renamed a class library?  It looks like you have two versions of EFUnitOfWork in two different classes; GodsCreationTaxidermy.Core and GodsCreationTaxidermy.Data, this may be the issue.

Comment: That's just how I do my Unif to work, I got EFUnitOfWork, EFUnitOfWorkFactory in GodsCreationTadisermy.Data and in ..Repository I have UnitOfWork, IUnitOfWork and IUnitOfWorkFactory ad that has always worked (used it in my last MVC 2 program (and never error-ed here in this project).

Comment: Kev I tried your route, moved everything into GodsCreationTaxidermy.Data and still am getting the same error

Comment: Kev, I just noticed the second version, in the main folder. Not sure how it got there but got past that error now,thanks.

Comment: Question, how can I mark this as resolved when everything was don't through comments (The last one from Kev Ritchie was the solution and I'd like him to get the credit for it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you recently renamed a class library? It looks like you have two versions of EFUnitOfWork in two different classes; GodsCreationTaxidermy.Core and GodsCreationTaxidermy.Data, this may be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I had a copy of my unit of work and repository, so that was 2 of everything and MVC didn't know what to do.